# Purging a SQL Server Service Broker Queue

Tags: sql-server-2008, service-broker

I have a service broker queue setup on a SQL 2008R2 server & I'm trying to empty the queue.  I'm running the [script specified here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/uk/sqlservicebroker/thread/633004f7-b0fa-443b-8e17-e888a9d11b15), which has always worked in the past, but now the queue is not being emptied despite this running.

Is there a better way to empty the queue?

Answer (score 0):

Better way to empty the queue is to always end conversation and both ends (both services) after processing all messages. In that case messages will be removed from queue.

Could it be possible that some other transaction is processing message at the time you run script?